# I anticipate slowness in this algorithm to check for vowels

Tags: c#, algorithm, string, search

The speed of the following alorithm would be determined by the number of words in the sentance and the number of characters in each word. I believe this is O(N^2)? or worse.

```
private bool CheckForNoVowels(string sentence)
{
    foreach (string word in sentence.Split(' '))
        foreach (char c in word)
            if (!vowels.Contains(c))
                return true;
}
```

Is there some sort of secret `string.HasVowel` Bill Gates is hiding from me? Is there a better, more efficient way to search for this. Thank you.

**intent**
I am trying to determine if the string is a company or a name, I assume if there is a word with no vowels, it is an abreviation or an acronym and that it is a company.

Comment: It's O(5 * 2n), which is O(n). (It's O(n) for copying + O(5 * n) for checking, with the 5 being for the number of vowels. But since 5 is a constant, it drops out, so it's O(n).)

Comment: FWIW, I don't see the point of splitting in your example. May as well just loop immediately.

Comment: Don't bother splitting into words first unless you actually care which word has the vowel.

Comment: The word 'try' doesn't contain a vowel but it's not a company name.  Look up "Named Entity Recognition" and you'll see that this is not an easy problem.

Comment: the word CIA contains two vowels ...

Comment: @belisarius: lol

@hightechrider: in the case of 'try' i would weigh it towards an orginazation rather than a person

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Regex.IsMatch(sentence, "[aoeui]");
```

Comment: Sorry, let me be more specific. If the string is "Discount Water LLC" I want to return true. If the string is "Discount Water" I want to return false. I have update the post with my intent.

Comment: @Tom Fobear: and now you'll get `true` as well, since it is non-vovel `D` in `Discount`

Comment: @Tom:  Also you'll hit a false positive on names with `Jr.`, `Sr.`, `Dr.`, and so on if you care about such a thing once you have the correct algorithm.

Comment: @indiv: Good point, I have a list of prefixs and suffixs so I will make sure they do not equal that.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's perfectly good. It would be considered O(N) in the total number of characters in the input. I can't imagine this would be the performance bottleneck in your app - but you should use profiling to check for sure.

Comment: "Perfectly good" ??? Surely the step where the code splits the text into words is unnecessary ...

Comment: It's unnecessary, but doesn't affect the O(N) running time. I agree that if the only point is to check for vowels, it should be `foreach (char in sentence)` instead.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what its internal implementation is (it is marked with [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall) and its algorithm doesn't appear to be documented)
, but I would try the [**`string.IndexOfAny`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/11w09h50.aspx) method.

> Reports the index of the first
>   occurrence in this instance of any
>   character in a specified array of
>   Unicode characters. Return Value: The
>   zero-based index position of the first
>   occurrence in this instance where any
>   character in anyOf was found; -1 if no
>   character in anyOf was found.

Do note that:

> The search for anyOf is
>   case-sensitive. This method performs
>   an ordinal (culture-insensitive)
>   search, where a character is
>   considered equivalent to another
>   character only if their Unicode scalar
>   value are the same. To perform a
>   culture-sensitive search, use the
>   CompareInfo.IndexOf method.

Example:

```
char[] vowels = { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };
bool hasVowel = word.IndexOfAny(vowels) != -1;
```

---

Off-topic, I don't understand why your code is splitting the sentence into words and then looking at every character in every word for a vowel. The split doesn't really seem to accomplish anything.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the time complexity to be determined based on the number of words in the sentence and the number of characters in each word, then you need two variables: the number of words, and the number of characters in each word. If you say *W* is the number of words, and *N* is the number of characters in the longest word, then your algorithm is O(W*N), not O(N^2).

Answer (score 0):

Why not remove the outer `foreach`? The most expensive thing here appears to be the `sentence.Split(' ')`, and eliminating that would merely cause the spaces to be checked for membership in `vowels`. Otherwise, this looks like an O(N) piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

Where ^2 comes from?

Split is O(N)

foreach(word...) foreach (c) - walk through each character exactly once - O(N) for both "foreach" together.

vowels.Contains is constant (if numer of vowels never change) or O(number of vowels).

As result O(N) or O(N*number of vowels).

Answer (score 0):

You could flatten the loop to avoid the unnecessary split and its string allocations, but at the end of the day you'll still have to check whether each character is a vowel:

```
private static readonly char[] _vowels = "AEIOUaeiou".ToCharArray();
private bool CheckForVowels(string sentence)
{
    return sentence.IndexOfAny(_vowels) != -1;
}
```

(I don't know the internal implementation of `IndexOfAny`. I'd imagine that it has to perform just such a loop, but chances are that it'll do it using unmanaged and/or unsafe code so will be at least as quick as anything you write yourself.)